# When did modular forms start to get studied via algebraic geometry?

Tags: mathematics, number-theory, algebraic-geometry

I'm looking, for instance, as to when people started studying modular curves and modular forms as sections of line bundles on them, as opposed to the point of view of modular forms being holomorphic functions on the upper half-plane satisfying some conditions.